# Why is stderr of subprocess None, if I raise exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stderr

I have two files `sub_p.py` which is a subprocess and a `runner.py` which runs the subprocess.

The code of `sub_p.py` is

```
raise RuntimeError("I am a generic Error")
```

the code of `runner.py` is

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run(['python3', 'sub.py'])

print(p.__dict__)
```

the result is
`{'args': ['python3', 'sub.py'], 'returncode': 1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None}`

Do the exceptions not get captured by stderr? Or should I specify anything in the run command?

Comment: I think you just need to set `capture_output=True`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: If you want to be able to catch the exception pythonically, you'll rather want to `import sub_p`.